# Estrutura de Dados, Alocação Dinâmica de Memória em C++ e leitura de dados

Tags: c++

Eu tenho um código com encapsulamento e composição com 3 classes em C++. No meu código eu tenho de ciar os objetos de forma estática mas quero criá-los de forma dinâmica. Eu tenho uma classe chamada trabalhador que tem 2 objetos de outras 2 classes (info e familia) como seus membros, de forma que trabalhador tem info e familia. Toda vez que eu quero criar um objeto trabalhador (que tem info e familia) eu tenho de fazê-lo de forma manual (estática) mas quero fazê-lo dinamicamente. Eu quero que o usuário escolha quantos trabalhadores ele quer criar dinamicamente. Eu acho que eu deveria usar estruturas de dados como uma lista e alocação dinâmica de memória mas eu não sei como fazê-lo. Meu código também cria um arquivo chamado "cadastro.dat" e eu quero ler esse arquivo mas também não sei como fazê-lo. Alguém poderia me ajudar? Estou mostrando o código que já fiz.

```
//MAIN
#include <iostream>
using std::cerr;
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::ios;

#include <fstream> 
using std::ofstream;

#include <cstdlib>
using std::exit;

#include "trabalhador.h"

int main()
{
    ofstream saidaArquivoCadastro( "cadastro.dat", ios::out );
    
    if ( !saidaArquivoCadastro ) // operador ! sobrecarregado
 {
 cerr << "Arquivo nao pode ser aberto" << endl;
 exit( 1 );
 }
 
    cout << "INFORME OS DADOS SOLICITADOS: \n\n";
    cout << "Nome do funcionario: ";
    info i1;
    cout << "\nCPF: ";
    info i2;
    cout << "\nNome da mae: ";
    familia f1;
    cout << "\nNome do pai: ";
    familia f2;
    trabalhador t(i1, i2, f1, f2);
    
    return 0;
}

//trabalhador.h
#ifndef TRABALHADOR_H
#define TRABALHADOR_H

#include "info.h"
#include "familia.h"

class trabalhador
{
    public:
        trabalhador (const info &, const info &, const familia &, const familia &);
        void print () const;
    private:
        const info funcionarioNome;
        const info funcionarioCPF;
        const familia mae;
        const familia pai;
};

#endif

//trabalhador.cpp
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

#include "trabalhador.h"
#include "info.h"

trabalhador::trabalhador (const info &infoNome, const info &infoCPF,
const familia &famiMae, const familia &famiPai)
:funcionarioNome (infoNome),
funcionarioCPF (infoCPF),
mae (famiMae),
pai (famiPai)
{
    cout << "\nDados do funcionario: \n";
    print();
}

void trabalhador::print() const
{
    funcionarioNome.print();
    funcionarioCPF.print();
    mae.print();
    pai.print();
}

//info.h
#include <string>
using std::string;

#ifndef INFO_H
#define INFO_H

class info
{
    public:
        info (string = "");
        void setInfoDado (string);
        void setInfo ();
        void print () const;
    private:
        string infoDado;
};

#endif

//info.cpp
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;

#include <string>
using std::string;
using std::getline;

#include "info.h"

info::info (string info)
{
    setInfoDado (info);
}

void info::setInfoDado (string info)
{
    infoDado = info;
    setInfo();
}

void info::setInfo ()
{   
    string nome;
    getline (cin, nome);
    infoDado = nome;
}

void info::print () const
{
    cout << infoDado << "\n";
}

//familia.h
#include <string>
using std::string;

#ifndef FAMILIA_H
#define FAMILIA_H

class familia
{
    public:
        familia (string = "");
        void setFamiDado (string);
        void setFami ();
        void print () const;
    private:
        string famiDado;
};

#endif

//familia.cpp
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;

#include <string>
using std::string;
using std::getline;

#include "familia.h"

familia::familia (string info)
{
    setFamiDado (info);
}

void familia::setFamiDado (string info)
{
    famiDado = info;
    setFami();
}

void familia::setFami ()
{   
    string nome;
    getline (cin, nome);
    famiDado = nome;
}

void familia::print () const
{
    cout << famiDado << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> No meu código eu tenho de ciar os objetos de forma estática mas quero
> criá-los de forma dinâmica. Eu tenho uma classe chamada trabalhador
> que tem 2 objetos de outras 2 classes (info e familia) como seus
> membros, de forma que trabalhador tem info e familia. Toda vez que eu
> quero criar um objeto trabalhador (que tem info e familia) eu tenho de
> fazê-lo de forma manual (estática) mas quero fazê-lo dinamicamente

O problema maior com seu código é que errou nos construtores para `info` e `família` e acabou ficando sem a implementação do construtor padrão dessas classes. E no caso da classe `trabalhador` não só não escreveu um construtor padrão mas ainda escreveu um único construtor que cria 2 instâncias de `familia` e duas de `info`, só que sem o construtor que você imaginava que iria ler os valores do teclado para o único campo dessas classes.
Veja:

```
class trabalhador
{
    public:
        trabalhador (const info &, const info &, const familia &, const familia &);
        void print () const;
    private:
        const info funcionarioNome;
        const info funcionarioCPF;
        const familia mae;
        const familia pai;
};
```

Poderia ter escrito do modo normal

```
class trabalhador
{
public:
    trabalhador() :
        funcionarioNome(info()),
        funcionarioCPF(info()),
        mae(familia()),
        pai(familia())
    {};
        
    trabalhador(
        const info&,
        const info&,
        const familia&,
        const familia&
    );
    void print() const;

private:
    const info funcionarioNome;
    const info funcionarioCPF;
    const familia mae;
    const familia pai;
};
```

E aí teria os dois construtores. E para criar alguns trabalhadores poderia escrever o normal:

```
    trabalhador* WorkForce = new trabalhador[20];
    WorkForce[19].print();
    delete[] WorkForce;
```

Note que do modo como escreveu as 3 classes não pode fazer nada com isso exceto chamar `print()` para o trabalhador.